# How to create own App Templates within docker Portainer container?

Tags: docker, containers, docker-registry, portainer, docker-repository

I'm pretty new to docker containers and played around a little bit.
During this, I played with portainer too and was wondering, how to create own App Templates without uploading files to GitHub.
Is there any Container Software?
Searching for a container local store where I can "upload" my docker-compose files to.
So I only need to change the Repository Link at Template creation in portainer.

Thanks

Comment: I would go a step further, use kubernetes and check out chartmuseum https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/chartmuseum to store and use helm chart privately.

Comment: Thank's for advice @ckaserer, i'll have a look at this soon.
For the moment i'm just trying to integrate some private registry to store all my docker-compose/docker-stack/app-template stuff. Unfortunatelly, Portainer doesn't seems to be able to connect against gitlab container...
Stuff like CI/CD from GitLab towards Portainer are easy going, but the other way around...